# Android E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe

Tags: java, android

I need to select a photo as user's icon in a settings fragment, and show map in another fragment. When there is only a settings fragment, photo picker is normal and useful.

However, as long as `FragmentTransaction` is added and map fragment is added, then the photo picker is not normal. The issue is that after selecting a photo from galley some times, if i want to take a photo using camera, the activity is break. The same break will happen if i take a photo using camera firstly.

What's more , if i delete the map fragment, then everything is OK.

Error info:

> 03-20 10:08:53.531 1196-3512/? E/LocSvc_eng: I/===> int     loc_eng_inject_location(loc_eng_data_s_type&, double, double, float) line 2119 
>       03-20 10:08:53.531 1196-3978/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02: I/<--- void globalRespCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientRespIndUnionType, void*) line 115 QMI_LOC_INJECT_POSITION_REQ_V02
>       03-20 10:08:53.551 24604-24656/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x800000c4abef40 in tid 24656 (GLThread 5661)
>       03-20 10:08:53.651 401-401/? A/DEBUG: *****               *****
>       03-20 10:08:53.651 401-401/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'HONOR/ATH-AL00/HWATH:6.0.1/HONORATH-AL00/C00B398:user/release-keys'
>       03-20 10:08:53.651 401-401/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
>       03-20 10:08:53.651 401-401/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
>       03-20 10:08:53.651 401-401/? A/DEBUG: pid: 24604, tid: 24656, name: GLThread 5661  >>> com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug <<<
>       03-20 10:08:53.651 401-401/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x800000c4abef40
>       03-20 10:08:53.681 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     x0   ffffffffffffffc0  x1   c0800000c4abef30  x2   0000000000000000  x3   fffffffffffffd40
>       03-20 10:08:53.681 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000002  x6   00000055c430a490  x7   00000055c4b42e10
>       03-20 10:08:53.681 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     x8   00000055c2b50000  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000038  x11  00000055c430a1d0
>       03-20 10:08:53.681 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     x12  00000055c4ba3fb0  x13  00000055c430a1d0  x14  0000000000000000  x15  0000000000000000
>       03-20 10:08:53.681 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000000000000001  x17  00000055c430a1d0  x18  0000000000000005  x19  0000000000000000
>       03-20 10:08:53.681 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     x20  00000000000002c0  x21  0000007f939e2000  x22  0000007f939e2000  x23  8000000000000000
>       03-20 10:08:53.681 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     x24  000000000000000e  x25  0000000000008000  x26  0000000000000000  x27  0000000000000281
>       03-20 10:08:53.681 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000000000000  x29  0000007f89851bb0  x30  0000000000000280
>       03-20 10:08:53.681 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f89851bb0  pc   0000007f939793a8  pstate 0000000060000000
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000000463a8  /system/lib64/libc.so (dlmalloc+3608)
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000019650  /system/lib64/libc.so (malloc+20)
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000000f7c  /system/lib64/libstdc++.so (_Znwm+16)
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000003b430  /data/app/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug-2/lib/arm64/libgdinamapv4sdk752.so
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000039678  /data/app/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug-2/lib/arm64/libgdinamapv4sdk752.so
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000000000000bba0  /data/app/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug-2/lib/arm64/libgdinamapv4sdk752.so (am_mapengine_new+28)
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000000000000c4d8  /data/app/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug-2/lib/arm64/libgdinamapv4sdk752ex.so (Java_com_autonavi_amap_mapcore_MapCore_nativeNewInstance+136)
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000000000cabeb0  /data/app/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug-2/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x7e3000) (long com.autonavi.amap.mapcore.MapCore.nativeNewInstance(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)+180)
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000000000cb0140  /data/app/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug-2/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x7e3000) (void com.autonavi.amap.mapcore.MapCore.newMap()+724)
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000001128df8  /data/app/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug-2/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x7e3000) (void com.amap.api.mapcore.util.b.af()+108)
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0000000001128810  /data/app/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug-2/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x7e3000) (void com.amap.api.mapcore.util.b.a(com.amap.api.mapcore.util.b)+68)
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0000000000ab9a24  /data/app/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug-2/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x7e3000) (void com.amap.api.mapcore.util.b$1.run()+104)
>       03-20 10:08:53.731 401-401/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0000000075072128  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x26bc000)
>       03-20 10:08:54.131 401-401/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_05
>       03-20 10:08:54.131 401-401/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
>       03-20 10:08:54.151 469-875/? E/logserver: process_one_event, can not find this event(data_app_native_crash@1489975734160.txt)
>       03-20 10:08:54.341 1196-1973/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'a86922e com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug.ActivityLogin (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>       03-20 10:08:54.341 1196-1973/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '8015f92 com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug/com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug.ActivityMain (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>       03-20 10:08:54.351 1196-4366/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
>       03-20 10:08:54.391 3789-3815/? E/DeviceInfo: file is not exist: /proc/ddr_info
>       03-20 10:08:54.391 3789-3815/? E/DeviceInfo: can't get ddr, default value: NULL
>       03-20 10:08:54.571 3789-3814/? E/PackageLogInfoManager: checkPackageLogState, cr: android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver@e13648a, packageNames: null
>       03-20 10:08:54.821 9187-9187/? E/wpa_supplicant: RSSI=-41;LINKSPEED=72;NOISE=9999;FREQUENCY=2427;
>       03-20 10:08:54.821 1196-1994/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=2427 BSSID=d4:ee:07:20:83:0c RSSI=-41 "plusub"WPA_PSK
>       03-20 10:08:55.081 1196-1214/? E/Sensors: setDelay, 173: handle=0, ns=10000000
>       03-20 10:08:55.081 1196-1214/? E/Sensors: setDelay, 855: handle=0, ns=10000000
>       03-20 10:08:55.081 1196-1971/? E/Sensors: read file ,buf = 4

FragmentSetting:

````
package com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.jph.takephoto.app.TakePhoto;
import com.jph.takephoto.app.TakePhotoFragment;
import com.jph.takephoto.compress.CompressConfig;
import com.jph.takephoto.model.CropOptions;
import com.jph.takephoto.model.TResult;
import com.zhy.m.permission.MPermissions;
import net.qiujuer.genius.ui.widget.EditText;
import java.io.File;
import static com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug.UtilsFinalArguments.IS_ADAPTED_ORIENTATION;
import static com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug.UtilsFinalArguments.REQUEST_CAMERO;
public class FragmentSetting extends TakePhotoFragment implements View.OnClickListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    //fragment_setting's view
    private View view;
    private ImageView containerImageView;
    private LinearLayout layout;
    private UtilsRenderScriptGaussianBlur blur;
    //layout UIs
    private Button chooseIconBtn;
    private ImageView userIconUIImg;
    private TextView userNameTxv;  
    ...

    //TakePhoto
    private TakePhoto takePhoto;
    private CropOptions cropOptions;
    private CompressConfig compressConfig;
    private File file;
    private Uri imageUri;
    //User Data
    private String userSex, userName;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting,container,false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        initView();
        initClickEvent();
        initData();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void initView() {
        userIconUIImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.uiImageView_userIcon);  
        chooseIconBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_choose_icon);  
...
    }
    private void initClickEvent() {
        chooseIconBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
...
    }

    private void initData() {
        takePhoto = getTakePhoto();
        cropOptions = new CropOptions.Builder().setAspectX(1).setAspectY(1).setWithOwnCrop(false).create();
        compressConfig=new CompressConfig.Builder().setMaxSize(50*1024).setMaxPixel(800).create();
        takePhoto.onEnableCompress(compressConfig,true);  //设置为需要压缩
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_choose_icon:
                MPermissions.requestPermissions(getActivity(), REQUEST_CAMERO, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                startDialog();
                break;
                 ...
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            IS_ADAPTED_ORIENTATION = 1;
        } else {
            IS_ADAPTED_ORIENTATION = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void takeSuccess(TResult result) {
        super.takeSuccess(result);
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String iconPath = result.getImage().getOriginalPath();
        Log.i("TAG", iconPath);
        Glide.with(this).load(iconPath).into(userIconUIImg);
        Log.i("TAG", iconPath);
    }

    //
    @Override
    public void takeFail(TResult result, String msg) {
        super.takeFail(result, msg);
    }

    //
    @Override
    public void takeCancel() {
        super.takeCancel();
    }

    /**
     * 弹出Dialog选择头像
     */
    private void startDialog() {


        dialogChooseIcon = new DialogChooseIcon(getActivity(), new DialogChooseIcon.IDialogChooseIconEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void listenDialogChooseIconEvent(int chooseFlag) {
                switch (chooseFlag) {
                    case 0:
                        file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/temp/"+System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                        if (!file.getParentFile().exists())file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        takePhoto.onPickFromCaptureWithCrop(imageUri,cropOptions);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/temp/"+System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                        if (!file.getParentFile().exists())file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        takePhoto.onPickFromGalleryWithCrop(imageUri, cropOptions);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        Window dialog_window = dialogChooseIcon.getWindow();  //获取到当前Activity的Window
        dialog_window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);  //设置对话框的位置
        WindowManager.LayoutParams dialog_window_attributes = dialog_window.getAttributes();  //获取到LayoutParams
        dialog_window_attributes.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;  //设置Dialog的长宽
        dialog_window_attributes.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        dialog_window_attributes.windowAnimations = R.style.dialogAnim;
        dialog_window.setAttributes(dialog_window_attributes);

        dialogChooseIcon.show();
        dialogChooseIcon.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                containerImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        dialogChooseIcon.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                containerImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }

}

```
````

ActivityMain.java

```
package com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.zhy.m.permission.MPermissions;
import com.zhy.m.permission.PermissionDenied;
import com.zhy.m.permission.PermissionGrant;
import static com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug.UtilsFinalArguments.REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
import static com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug.UtilsFinalArguments.REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
import static com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug.UtilsFinalArguments.REQUEST_USUAL;

public class ActivityMain extends BaseActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    //基本的UI部件
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private TextView toolbarTitle;

    //碎片管理FragmentManager
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager = null;
    /**
     * 1
     */
    private FragmentMainMap fragmentMainMap = null;
    private FragmentSetting fragmentSetting = null;
    private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setImmersiveMode();

        initBaseView();

        initMapFirst();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.seek_mode_menu_item:
                hideAllFragment(mFragmentTransaction);
                /**
                 * 2
                 */
                if(fragmentMainMap == null){
                    fragmentMainMap = new FragmentMainMap();
                    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_layout,fragmentMainMap);
                }else{
                    mFragmentTransaction.show(fragmentMainMap);
                }
                toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
                toolbarTitle.setText("WeMeet");
                break;
            case R.id.setting_menu_list:
                hideAllFragment(mFragmentTransaction);
                if (fragmentSetting == null){
                    fragmentSetting = new FragmentSetting();
                    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_layout,fragmentSetting);
                }else {
                    mFragmentTransaction.show(fragmentSetting);
                }
                //修改标题栏标题
                toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
                toolbarTitle.setText(R.string.action_settings);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
        //点击某一项菜单项取消选中状态并关闭drawer
        //item.setCheckable(false);
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void initBaseView() {
        //Toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            toolbar.setTitle("");
            toolbar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_toolbar);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "toolbar == null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //DrawerLayout
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        //NavigationView
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "navigationView == null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        //nav_header
        View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);   //没有这一行时，drawerUserNameTxv的findviewById的结果是null
        drawerUserNameTxv = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        drawerUserIcon = (UtilsCircleImageView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        MPermissions.requestPermissions(ActivityMain.this, REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        MPermissions.requestPermissions(ActivityMain.this, REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }

    /**
     * 初始化显示地图
     */
    private void initMapFirst() {
        /**
         *3
         */
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if(fragmentMainMap == null){
            fragmentMainMap = new FragmentMainMap();
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_layout,fragmentMainMap);
        }else{
            mFragmentTransaction.show(fragmentMainMap);
        }
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    /**
     * 隐藏所有Fragment
     * @param fragmentTransaction
     */
    private void hideAllFragment(FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction){
        /**
         * 4
         */
        if (fragmentMainMap != null){
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentMainMap);
        }
        if (fragmentSetting != null){
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentSetting);
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//申请权限
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.john.wemeet_11_debug"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        //高斯模糊处理
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    //申请权限
    apt 'com.zhy:mpermission-compiler:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.zhy:mpermission-api:1.0.0'
    //Material Design
    compile 'net.qiujuer.genius:ui:2.0.0-beta4'
    //TakePhoto
    compile 'com.jph.takephoto:takephoto_library:4.0.3'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: You're accessing an illegal memory location in C code, somewhere after calling Java_com_autonavi_amap_mapcore_MapCore_nativeNewInstance.    I'd check all the references passed to that library for nulls, and make sure that it isn't holding on to references after they've been garbage collected.  Based on the address it doesn't look like a null pointer dereference.